# Can a gitlab CI script be reused using branch specific variables?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner, gitlab-ce

I have a gitlab CI script which deploys a website using a runner on the webserver. There are multiple deployments (depending aon the branch). The script is always the same except from the htdocs directory where the files are copied to.

```
stages:
  - build
  - deploy

pages:
  stage: build
  script:
  - hugo
  artifacts:
    paths:
    - public/

deploy_to_test:
  stage: deploy
  tags:
    - web-deploy
  script:
    - rsync -av --omit-dir-times --no-owner --delete public/ /var/www/wwwtest.my/
    - find /var/www/wwwtest.my/ -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;
    - find /var/www/wwwtest.my/ -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;
  environment:
    name: test
  only:
    - develop


deploy_to_prod:
  stage: deploy
  tags:
    - web-deploy
  script:
    - rsync -av --omit-dir-times --no-owner --delete public/ /var/www/www.my/
    - find /var/www/www.my/ -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;
    - find /var/www/www.my/ -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;
  environment:
    name: prod
  only:
    - master
```

Is it somehow possible to adher to the DRY principle and just set the htdocs directory as a branch dependent variable and reuse the deployment script?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define a YAML template that you can reuse across jobs.
Each job can define custom variables that can be utilized by the templated script.

Example:

```
.template: &template
  stage: deploy
  tags:
    - web-deploy
  script:
    - **Use the $HTDOCS variable**

deploy_to_test:
  <<: *template
  environment:
    name: prod
  variables:
    - HTDOCS: foo
  only:
    - master
```

More info [here](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#anchors) and [here](https://medium.com/@rossinigiovanni/gitlab-ci-how-to-reuse-your-yml-code-96a82b3d587e).

Comment: Could you give me a reference for that syntax. I can find it neither in the gitlab documentation nor in the YAML spec.

Comment: Sorry about not providing a reference:

Gitlab docs: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#anchors

Another article: https://medium.com/@rossinigiovanni/gitlab-ci-how-to-reuse-your-yml-code-96a82b3d587e